What's $\sigma-$similarity?
I am reading Octonions, Jordan Algebras and Exceptional Groups by Tonny A. Springer and Ferdinand D. Veldkamp. I am confusing about the definition of $\sigma\text{-}$similarity.

Let $V_i(i=1,2)$ be vector space over field $k_i$, with nondegenerate quadratic forms $N_i$ and associated bilinear forms $< , >_i$. A  $\sigma\text{-}$similarity $t$ of $V_1$ onto $V_2$, where $\sigma$ is an isomorphism of $k_1$ onto $k_2$, is a surjective $\sigma\text{-}$linear mapping such that $$N_2(t(x))=n(t)\sigma(N_1(x))$$ for some $n(t)\in k^*$.

However, what is $\sigma\text{-}$linear mapping? Since $k_i$ should not necessarily be the same, it can't be linear map like $t(x+y)=t(x)+t(y)$ and $t(kx)=kt(x)$. I can't find definition of it.
Thanks for your help!

I would guess that $\sigma$-linearity is $t(\alpha x + \beta y) = \sigma(\alpha)t(x) + \sigma(\beta)t(y)$.

As one commenter Nicholas Todoroff already said, to me, given that $\sigma$ is an isomorphism of $k_1$ onto $k_2$, $\sigma$-linearity of $t$ reads "$\forall x,y\in V_1$, $\forall k\in k_1$, $t(x+y) = t(x) + t(y)$ and $t(kx) = \sigma(k)t(x)$". It coincides with linearity when $k_1 = k_2$ and $\sigma = Id$.
Edit with wikipedia definition : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semilinear_map

Thank you! I have seen semilinear map before I asked this question. But it use the the term 'semilinear', which makes me confused. I'm not sure the meaning of 'linear' in the book is the same as the meaning of 'semilinear' in wiki, that's why I asked this question. It seems they are the same thing so far. Did you see the $\sigma\text{-}$ linear map in any other books?

Yes, it turns out the notion resurfaces under different names, such as in this paper https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/CE8731F584E98F0225C1E7B6D141F8F6/S0017089500020164a.pdf/semilinear-transformations-over-finite-fields-are-frobenius-maps.pdf
@MGIO There seems to be no consensus over which of "semilinearity", "$\sigma$-linearity" or even "$\sigma$-semilinearity" is to be preferred. The oldest book I've seen that mentions semilinearity is the one by the Bourbaki collective on Algebra (over modules). See "Algebra I, Bourbaki" page 223
